# SLComposeViewController Is there anyway to bypass settings view after user registers first time facebook and twitter accounts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-framework

I am working with the iOS application which shares post on facebook and twitter. My problem is when i post first time to facebook or twitter. I am getting this alert [image]

On clicking setttings button, i am redirected to Settings View. But after Login success i need to close the settings view and go back to my application and reopen it to post on twitter/facebook. Is there anyway to bypass settings view and show my application view directly after register success? I dont wanna close settings view and reopen my application. 
Waiting for your hint ;)
Thank you.

Comment: try to add ur account details first and try

Comment: @sanjeet - I added my account, its woriking fine. My issue is can i redirect my application view after adding my account details on settings view?